# Behavior of Velocity Distribution under Lorentz Boost

Tags: special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, phase-space

I'm trying to relate the velocity distribution function $f(v)$, defined over phase space such that $f(v)d^3v d^3x$ is the number of particles in the phase space volume $d^3vd^3x$, between two frames, say F1 and F2. I can't really find an expression relating the two, with the exception of [Lee 1969 ApJ vol 155](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1969ApJ...155..687L) (PDF), equation 7 specifically. I tried using the Lorentz invariant phase space element, and relating the momentum differential to the velocity differential via

$$
\frac{dp}{dv} = m \gamma^3
$$

where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor for $v$. The expression I obtain at the end is, after enforcing particle number conservation $f^{\prime}d^3v^{\prime}d^3x^{\prime} = f d^3v d^3x$ and using $\frac{dx^{\prime}}{dx}=\gamma(v_\text{boost})$,

\begin{align}
f^{\prime}(v^{\prime}) &= f(V)*\left(\frac{\gamma(v^{\prime})}{\gamma(V)} \right)^3 \gamma(v_\text{boost})\frac{E}{E^{\prime}} \\
&= f(V)\left(\frac{\gamma(v^{\prime})}{\gamma(V)} \right)^2
\gamma(v_\text{boost})
\end{align}

However, this doesn't agree with the paper above, as I am missing one factor of $\left(\frac{\gamma(v^{\prime})}{\gamma(V)} \right)$, but I can't see where I went wrong.